# Spring Boot only initializes one data source but not the other

Tags: java, spring-boot, datasource, multiple-databases

I have followed multiple articles on creating multiple data sources and tried the same in my code. But strangely spring boot in only initializing one data source and not the other. When I remove any one of them from the code, the other is created without any issues. Any idea.

Bean Configuration -

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfiguration {

    @Bean("dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "p.datasource")
    public DataSource pDataSource() {
        System.out.println("**************************> dataSource");
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean("storeFrontDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "c.datasource")
    public DataSource cDataSource() {
        System.out.println("**************************> storeFrontDataSource");
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

YML File (removed some data for confidentiality) -

```
p:
  datasource:
    url: {some-url}
    driver-class-name: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    username: abc
    password: xyz
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    hikari:
      schema:        
      connection-init-sql: select 1 from dual
      minimum-idle: 25
      maximum-pool-size: 100 
      idle-timeout: 10_000
      max-lifetime: 20_000
      connection-timeout: 1_000
      validation-timeout: 500

c:
  datasource:
    url: {some-url}
    driver-class-name: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    username: abc
    password: xyz
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    hikari:
      schema:        
      pool-name: uspo-cis-sf-pool
      connection-init-sql: select 1 from dual
      minimum-idle: 1
      maximum-pool-size: 5 
      idle-timeout: 10_000
      max-lifetime: 50_000
      connection-timeout: 2_000 
      validation-timeout: 500
```

Error thrown -

Only the "datasource" bean is found and not the "storeFrontDataSource" bean. Even on the console only one of System.out.println() is called (i.e. for "datasource") while other is not printed. **SpringBoot is not even initializing the other bean definition.**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=storeFrontDataSource)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1346) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

Note - Even defining @Primary doesn't helps. Both System.out.println() should be printed to console regardless.

Comment: At the site where you inject the bean, try injecting DataSource instead of HikariDataSource, perhaps the HikariDataSource is being wrapped.

Comment: I am injecting the data source with the bean qualifier. If I put @Primary on the "storeFrontDataSource" then its created and the we get error for the "dataSource" bean not found. Irrespective of the usage, the System.out.println() must be invoked which is strange.

Comment: What's the type you've declared where you've `@Autowired` it?

Comment: Please add the code with injection of the data source to your question

Comment: Today after the good sleep I re-scan the code and found that the user of these 2 datasources are in the dependent library and they are injecting HikariDataSource for both the datasources. I will fix it to see if it resolves the issue, but why its working for one and not for other datasource ?

Comment: After fixing the code in the dependent library the issue is resolved. But I still wonder how it worked for one and not the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the advise @tgdavies, I found some of the classes from the dependent libraries were injecting 'HikariDataSource' instead of 'DataSource'. After fixing them the issue got resolved.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create customer configuration class for create multiple datosource and you define primary datasource.

Check this example from [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases)

Comment: Why should I do custom configuration, when the same article says you can do it with auto configuration?